# how to set value of request.user_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

```
get "/"
```

and inside controller I have action that depends on browser When I run my test it fails because `request.user_client` is nil What can I do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set header value

```
get '/', {}, {"User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.7) Gecko/20100723 Fedora/3.6.7-1.fc13 Firefox/3.6.7'}
```